# recursion don´t go to the step back when finishing the last step

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm working on a program that can solve algorithms, and I am using recursion to do so, but when it is checking if it can place a number and it can't it will just end the program, and no looking back to change the number before, can anyone help me. Here is my code:

```
public static void dfs(int x, int y, int value )

{
    if(matriz[x][y]==0)
    {
        SudokuSolved[x][y]=value;
    }
    boolean br= breakrule(x,y);
    if (br==false)
    {
        sol = solved();
    }
    if(solved()==false&&br==false)
    {
        f++;
        if (f>=9)
        {
            f=0;
            c++;
        }
        for (int num=1;num<10;num++)
        {               
            dfs(f,c,num);
        }
    }
    if(solved()==true&&br==false)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<9;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            System.out.print('|');
            for (int j=0; j<9;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(SudokuSolved[i][j]);
                System.out.print('|');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------");
    }
}
```

any tip or suggestion is well appreciated

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Comment: solving a sudoku**

Comment: id tried but can´t find why it wont go back

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose from the code you've supplied but it looks as though you are misunderstanding the way backtracking works. In pseudocode your algorithm should be something like:

```
test value:
    change state to include value
    if state is legal
        if state is complete
            use completed state
        else
            test all possible values in next step
    change state to remove value
```

Try changing your code to match that pattern.

As an example, if you have well encapsulated classes to represent a Sudoko board then the code to solve might be:

```
private void solve(Board board, CellValue value) {
    board.add(value);
    if (board.isLegal()) {
        if (board.isComplete()) {
            useSolution(board);
        } else {
            Cell cell = board.firstEmptyCell();
            for (Value value: Value.values())
                solve(board, new CellValue(cell, value));
        }
    }
    board.remove(value);
}
```

Comment: mmm... maybe i´m wrong but what i have read when the recursive algorithm ends it should go back to the previous step with the values in that step right? and to the next line where it was called in this case to a for loop that will change the value to keep seeking but when i try to run this when it "returns" it will just go on disregarding the for loop. and i already redo the code to seek the problem

Comment: @FernandoAyalaAvila I'll add an example so you can see what I mean